# Defining destination Activity for a Button

Tags: java, android, xml, button, android-activity

I found this code very usefull to get from one activity to the other but the problem is, that I don't see where the destination is mentioned. I would really appreciate it if some one pointed out how to change the destination.

Here is the code:

```
Button getTaxi = (Button) findViewById(R.id.GetTaxi);
    getTaxi.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(final View view) {
            final Intent intent = new Intent();
            setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
            finish();
        }
    });
```

The respective part in the xml:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/GetTaxi"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:text="GetTaxi" >
</Button>
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the code that executes on the `Button`'s click states that your `Activity` (which is a sub-activity here by the way) has done its job and now finishes with the result code `RESULT_OK`. It means that there was another `Activity` that has started this actual `Activity` for some kind of result. So, when you'll click the `Button` your `Activity` will finish. To start some other `Activity` on the `Button`'s click you should create an `Intent`, specifying explicitly the `Activity` you want to start, or just the action you want to perform over some data, letting the Android resolve the final `Activity` for you. Then you should call `startActivity()`, passing in the `Intent` you've created. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for opening my eyes. Yes this actually is a sub Activity.
The code part i was looking for is on the main Activity of course.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
Button getTaxi = (Button) findViewById(R.id.GetTaxi);
getTaxi.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(final View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClass(this, GetTaxiActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
      //call finish() if the current activity is something like a loading page
    }
});
```

The code piece above which you mentioned is a sub-activity which is called using 
StartActivityForResult();